# Question on Projective Dimensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

$\require{AMScd}$I have a question regarding a claim in *A first course of homological algebra* by *Northcott*. I think it's very easy, since the author didn't provide a proof, and just kind of claimed it. It's on page 76. And it says:

> Let $0 \to A_1 \to P \to A \to 0$ is exact, and $P$ is projective, then $\mbox{Pd}(A) = \mbox{Pd}(A_1) + 1$, provided that $\mbox{Pd}(A) > 0$.
>
> Where $\mbox{Pd}(A)$ denotes the *projective dimension* of $A$, i.e if $A$ has a projective resolution $0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to... \to P_1 \to P_0 \to A \to 0$, where all $P_i$'s are projective, and there's no shorter resolution. Then we'll write $\mbox{Pd}(A) = n$.

## Question

Ok, so how can I prove it?

I can get to the point that $\mbox{Pd}(A) \le \mbox{Pd}(A_1) + 1$, by assuming that $\mbox{Pd}(A_1) = n$, i.e there exists a projective resolution of $A_1$, which looks like this: $0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to... \to P_1 \to P_0 \to A_1 \to 0$, since $P_0 \to A_1$ is epic, and $A_1 \to P$ is monic, I can combine the 2 mappings, and arrive the following resolution: $0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to... \to P_1 \to P_0 \to P \to A \to 0$, which means that $\mbox{Pd}(A) \le n+1$.

But I cannot prove that $\mbox{Pd}(A) = n+1$. Here's how I start, assume that $A$ has a resolution: $0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to... \to P_1 \to P_0 \to A \to 0$, and I'll try to construct a resolution for $A'$ that lacks $P_0$, i.e, what I'm trying to prove is, if $\mbox{Pd}(A) < n+1$, then $\mbox{Pd}(A_1) < n$ (which is, of course not right, since we assume $\mbox{Pd}(A_1) = n$). So here's how it goes:

$\begin{CD}@. @. @. 0 @>>> A_1 @>\chi>> P @>\sigma>> A @>>> 0\\
@. @. @. @. @. @. @| \\
0 @>>> P_n @>\chi_n>> P_{n-1} @>\chi_{n-1}>> ... @>\chi_2>> P_1 @>\chi_1>> P_0 @>\chi_0>> A @>0>> 0 \\
\end{CD}$

Since $\sigma$ is epic, and $P_0$ is projective, hence there exists: $\gamma_0: P_0 \to P$, such that the square commutes:

$\begin{CD}@. @. @. 0 @>>> A_1 @>\chi>> P @>\sigma>> A @>>> 0\\
@. @. @. @. @. @A\gamma_0AA @| \\
0 @>>> P_n @>\chi_n>> P_{n-1} @>\chi_{n-1}>> ... @>\chi_2>> P_1 @>\chi_1>> P_0 @>\chi_0>> A @>0>> 0 \\
\end{CD}$

Since $\sigma (\gamma_0 \chi_1) = 0$, and the former row is exact, hence there exists $\gamma_1: P_1 \to A$, such that the square commutes.

$\begin{CD}@. @. @. 0 @>>> A_1 @>\chi>> P @>\sigma>> A @>>> 0\\
@. @. @. @. @A\gamma_1AA @A\gamma_0AA @| \\
0 @>>> P_n @>\chi_n>> P_{n-1} @>\chi_{n-1}>> ... @>\chi_2>> P_1 @>\chi_1>> P_0 @>\chi_0>> A @>0>> 0 \\
\end{CD}$

One problem remains is that $\gamma_1$ is not epic, so, I cannot have the resolution: $0 \to P_n \to ... \to P_1 \to A_1 \to 0$.

Can my proof be improved, or should I tackle it in a complete different way?

Thank you guys very much in advance,

And have a good day,

## Edit

I still don't see how we can use Schanuel's lemma to tackle this problem, ok so I assume $\mbox{Pd}(A) < n + 1$, i.e, I'll have the resolution $\begin{CD} @. @. @. @. @. 0 \\ @. @. @. @. @. @VVV \\ 0 @>>> P_n @>>> P_{n - 1} @>>> ... @>>> P_0 @>>> A_1 @>>> 0 \\ @. @. @. @. @. @VVV \\ @. @. @. @. @. P \\ @. @. @. @. @. @VVV \\ 0 @>>> Q_n @>>> Q_{n - 1} @>>> ... @>>> Q_0 @>>> A @>>> 0 \\ @. @. @. @. @. @VVV \\ @. @. @. @. @. 0 \end{CD}$

How can I apply Schanuel's lemma to find a resolution for $A_1$ that has length no larger than $n - 1$?

Comment: You'll want to use Schanuel's lemma to combine the projective resolutions so you do get epic gammas. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_lemma

Comment: Is that the definition of projective dimension that you are to work with? By chance has he characterized projective dimension using Ext?

Comment: @JohnMyers: I'm not sure what you mean by "characterized projective dimension using Ext", but since this claim appears at a half page from where the section about Projective Dimension starts, so I don't think he has characterized it using Ext yet, the definition at the top is what I think I should be using.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks for your hint, I have looked at the former Schanuel's lemma for ses, and the generalized version for les, but at the moment, I haven't thought of a way to use it here. I'm going to school now, so I'll think about at it later. Thanks very much.

Comment: OK, nevermind my comment then. You can characterize the projective dimension of a module $M$ using the vanishing of $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,-)$, and this problem can be done quickly using that machinery. I haven't seen Northcott's book, but surely you'll learn it soon!

Comment: @JackSchmidt: I still cannot get how we can use the Schanuel's lemma to tackle this problem. I've editted my post, since I cannot draw commutative diagrams in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a minimal resolution $Q^\bullet$ of $A_1$, tagging it onto $P \rightarrow A$ gives a resolution of $A$, so $\dim A_1 + 1 \geqslant \dim A$.

To see that $\dim A_1 + 1 \leqslant \dim A$, compare $Q^\bullet$ with a minimal resolution: $$0 \rightarrow P_{\dim A} \rightarrow \ldots P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$$$$0 \rightarrow \ker Q_{\dim A - 2} \rightarrow \ldots Q_0 \rightarrow P \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$$By the Generalized Schanuel's lemma, we know that $\ker Q_{\dim A - 2}$ is projective, so $0 \rightarrow \ker Q_{\dim A - 2} \rightarrow \ldots Q_0 \rightarrow A_1 \rightarrow 0$ is a resolution of  $A_1$ of length $\dim A - 1$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you very very much, I get it now :d :*

Comment: I have one question, maybe I understand it wrongly, but is your projective solution for $A_1$ the following sequence: $0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to ... \to P_2 \to P_1 \oplus F \to A_1 \to 0$? If so, how can I prove exactness at $P_1 \oplus F$?

Comment: Yup, I can show that $0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to ... \to P_2 \to P_1 \oplus F \to P_0 \oplus F \to A \to 0$ is an exact sequence, but how can I prove that $0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to ... \to P_2 \color{red}{\to P_1 \oplus F \to A_1} \to 0$ is exact at $P_1 \oplus F$?

Comment: hmm yep it need not be exact there

Comment: I'll unmark the answer so others can take a look at it, I really hope you don't mind. I found out the error, when trying to apply the same thing to prove another similar theorem on Injective Dimension. :(

Comment: no problem at all - glad you found it

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very clever. :*